# browser window height = div height - 80px

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am trying to make a template where I have a header bar of height 80px. And followed by a slider of height equal to browser window height. 
For setting the slider height equal to browser window height I am using the following jQuery code.

```
 jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('#sequence') .css({'height': ((jQuery(window).height()))+'px'});
    jQuery(window).resize(function(){
        jQuery('#sequence') .css({'height': ((jQuery(window).height()))+'px'});
    });
});
```

It's working great & re-sizing the slider height. My header bar height is 80px and I want to re-size my slider height something like this.

> browser window height = slider height - 80px(header bar height)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if it working, try so `css({ 'height': ((jQuery(window).height()) - 80) + 'px'});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`css({ 'height': ((jQuery(window).height()) - 80) + 'px'});`